# How to use getComputeAttributeImportance from WEKA random forest in java code to print out the importance of features?

Tags: java, weka

I have used WEKA API in my java code to train and test a random forest on my data. However when I am trying to print out importance of features in my java code as :

System.out.println(RF.getComputeAttributeImportance());

All i get is 'true'

what is the correct way to use this method for printing attribute importance?

Cheers!

Comment: What exactly you want to see?

Comment: I would like to be able to output something like this in my code :             0.63 (   238)  petallength 
      0.55 (    67)  sepalwidth 
      0.55 (   133)  sepallength 
      0.53 (   168)  petalwidth